# Conexão local Sql Server Express 2017 - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando conectar no Sql Server Express 2017 via Visual Studio (conexão local), mas fica me retornando esse erro sempre quando tenta abrir:

> Uma conexão com o servidor foi estabelecida com êxito, mas ocorreu um
>   erro durante o processo de logon. (provider: Shared Memory Provider,
>   error: 0 - Não há processo no outro extremo do pipe.

String de Conexão:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-5UDKJ7M\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Dev;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Percebi que existem 2 *Web.Config*, na raiz da aplicação(2) e na raiz das pastas(1), neste caso qual deles deve ter a string de conexão ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No da raiz, não mexa no web.config das views :P

Comment: Ps.: o erro não me parece ser no web.config mas sim na configuração do banco

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075784/error-message-provider-shared-memory-provider-error-0-no-process-is-on-th#8076038